# Sum in a merged dataframe without adding duplicate values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes which I merge as below:

```
import pandas as pd

d1 = {'HAL_NACHSC': ['03539001', '03531028', '03530018', '03530018', '03539001', '03530017', '03531028', '03530016', '03531031', '03531030', '03537002', '03537001', '03531029'], 'Q': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
d2 = {'HAL_VONSCH': ['03539003', '03537001', '03530019', '03539001', '03539002', '03530018', '03531029', '03530017', '03531032', '03531031', '03530016', '03537002', '03531030'], 'Q': [0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9, -10, -11, -12]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)

SigmaQ = df1.merge(df2, left_on='HAL_NACHSC', right_on='HAL_VONSCH', how='outer')
```

Which gives SigmaQ as

```
 HAL_NACHSC   Q_x HAL_VONSCH   Q_y
0    03539001   0.0   03539001  -3.0
1    03539001   4.0   03539001  -3.0
2    03531028   1.0        NaN   NaN
3    03531028   6.0        NaN   NaN
4    03530018   2.0   03530018  -5.0
5    03530018   3.0   03530018  -5.0
6    03530017   5.0   03530017  -7.0
7    03530016   7.0   03530016 -10.0
8    03531031   8.0   03531031  -9.0
9    03531030   9.0   03531030 -12.0
10   03537002  10.0   03537002 -11.0
11   03537001  11.0   03537001  -1.0
12   03531029  12.0   03531029  -6.0
13        NaN   NaN   03539003   0.0
14        NaN   NaN   03530019  -2.0
15        NaN   NaN   03539002  -4.0
16        NaN   NaN   03531032  -8.0
```

I now want to identify all entries which have the same values in the columns `HAL_NACHSC` and `Q_x` or in `HAL_VONSCH` and `Q_y`, **except** for the `NaN` entries, I want to keep those.
The ultimate goal is to sum up the Q's for every number in `HAL_NACHSC` and `HAL_VONSCH` without adding duplicates.
Beyond that I need something that works really fast, since I need to execute this a lot of times, therefore I'm not even sure my merging approach is the best way to do that.

The expected result for the sum would look like that

```
 HAL_NACHSC   Q_x_sum HAL_VONSCH   Q_y_sum
0    03539001   4.0   03539001  -3.0
1    03531028   7.0        NaN   NaN
2    03530018   5.0   03530018  -5.0
3    03530017   5.0   03530017  -7.0
4    03530016   7.0   03530016 -10.0
5    03531031   8.0   03531031  -9.0
6    03531030   9.0   03531030 -12.0
7    03537002  10.0   03537002 -11.0
8    03537001  11.0   03537001  -1.0
9    03531029  12.0   03531029  -6.0
10        NaN   NaN   03539003   0.0
11        NaN   NaN   03530019  -2.0
12        NaN   NaN   03539002  -4.0
13        NaN   NaN   03531032  -8.0
```

Such that I can apply `SigmaQ.sum(axis=1, numeric_only=True)`. I don't necessarily need the above dataframe for my work, it is fine if I get the sum directly.

Edit: For context and maybe better understanding of my question: The numbers in `HAL_NACHSC` and `HAL_VONSCH` represent IDs of shafts where sewers end or start respectively. `Q` represents the in- or outflow of the corresponding shafts. Since one shaft might have multiple starting sewers but only one ending sewer (or vice-versa) I need to eliminate the duplicates in order not to count any flow double.

Comment: You can achieve everything except the duplicate elimination by using `.groupby` and `sum`.  Your requirement seems a bit odd.  You end up with a row that has multiple samples of `Q_x` but only a single sample of `Q_y`.  Wouldn't `mean` be a better metric to use?

Comment: @TimRoberts What exactly do you mean by "multiple samples of `Q_x`? For every number in `HAL_NACHSC` (or `HAL_VONSCH`) I want one (summed up) value for `Q_x` and one for `Q_y` without counting the same Q multiple times. Also how would `mean` be of help?

Comment: In your first result line, your Q_x_sum has the sum of TWO samples, and Q_y_sum has the sum of ONE sample.  I'm just saying that's an unusual technique.  Usually, if you are grouping lines by a key, you want each output column to represent ALL of the input samples, either as a sum or an average.

Comment: @TimRoberts Ok I see what you mean. Maybe my edit helps for better understanding what I want to achieve. Considering this I think `mean` is not the way to go. Your observation comes from the fact that the first shaft has two ending sewers but only one starting sewer.